# index.php removal in .htaccess doesn't work when on https

Tags: htaccess, .htaccess, rewrite, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess setup:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # force https for all URLs in /admin.php
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
        RewriteRule ^admin.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        # Redirect index.php Requests
        # ------------------------------
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

        # Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
        # ------------------------------
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This all works great, when a user goes to /admin.php they are forced to use https and when everywhere else they just use http. However if you navigate to a front end page using the https protocol you'll get a 404 error.

Seems to be because the index.php removal technique isn't working for https, for example:

https://domain.com/page - doesn't work
https://domain.com/index.php/page - does work

http://domain.com/page - does work
http://domain.com/index.php/page - does work

I can't work out what I need to change to make it work when in https as, as far as I can tell there isn't https/http specified in my htaccess for the index.php removal? Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many default SSL setup have settings to ignore .htaccess at all. So server use your .htaccess for http, but for security reason ignore default rules overwrite for https.
Check your ssl config (try - /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf) what flag you have for [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)?   Possible you have **None** - in this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem. Change it to **FileInfo**.

Comment: Thanks Max, we're unfortunately on shared hosting so have requested this info from the hosting provider.

Comment: Cheers, this fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this ::

1.) Go to your SSL configuration file : `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.con`

2.) Find your Virtual Host : `<VirtualHost_default_:443>`

3.) Write down : Path to your directory

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/magento">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

4.) Restart your apache : `service httpd restart`